Fourier transform of differential form
I'm trying to make sense of how to take the Fourier transform(FT) of the Yang-Mills gauge field $A=A_\mu dx^\mu \in \Omega^1(M)$, where $M$ is $\mathbb{R}^4$, let's say. A shortcut to this problem would simply be to consider only the coefficients $A_\mu$, which are functions on $M$ and it is obvious how to perform a FT on them. However, for the eventual aim of my calculation, this is not enough and I need to perform a FT on $A$.
I came across this paper that seems to explain exactly how to perform a FT of differential forms, but I'm not sure if I fully understand what they do. I see that they treat $x$ and $dx$ as coordinates on a supermanifold, where they then define the FT, which I am okay with. However, when they write the FT of the example in equation 2.20, it seems like the FT of a $2$-form on $\mathbb{R}^3$ is a $1$-form. I don't really have an intuition why this must be the case. Also, would that mean that the FT of $A$ on $\mathbb{R}^4$ becomes a $3$-form?
I know that this is not a very concrete question, but any context/examples would be helpful. Thanks in advance!
Edit: typo

What is the eventual aim of your calculation?  Without that context it’s hard to know what you’re trying to do.

The aim will be to compute some correlators, which contain integrals over $\mathbb{R}^4$, so it would be necessary to understand what happens to the measure and a part of the measure is given by $A$. Well okay, like I said this can be avoided by considering only the coefficients and maybe it not true that this wouldn't be enough for my calculation after all. However, the questions remains as a curiosity: how about a Fourier transform of differential forms?

I'd have to do more reading to give an actual answer, but my gut on this is that your confusion is primarily thinking there's something there that there's not.  Any Fourier transform that you can actually calculate is ultimately going to be in terms of some finite number of coefficients.  Defining a Fourier transform on any mathematical object is only meaningful inasmuch as we can interpret the results, so the motivation is (to some degree) inextricable from the definition.  Try "inverting" your search strategy; start with applications adjacent to yours and look for common formalisms.
